# How can you write to a Databricks catalog from R

Tags: r, apache-spark, databricks, sparklyr

I am currently trying to connect to databricks from a remote RStudio server.

Using the python package databricks-connect and sparklyr I am able to connect and read in delta tables from a catalog on databricks using the `tbl()` function  and `in_catalog` parameter.

However, how much I try, I do not seem to be able to *write* delta tables to a catalog. Has anyone succeeded in this?

Tried different functions. `sdf_copy_to()` came closest, but it seem to not support catalogs.

Comment: Relevant: https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/3397